# Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have
`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

`DemoApplication.java`

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`GreetingController.java`

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

`ServletInitializer.java`

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Get your greeting <a href="/greeting">here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

`greeting.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

`application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/erp
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/erp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

# Controller - View JSP.
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

# Logging. Not working.
logging.path=target/logs
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR

# THYMELEAF (ThymeleafAutoConfiguration)
#spring.thymeleaf.cache=true # Enable template caching.
#spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true # Check that the template exists before rendering it.
#spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true # Check that the templates location exists.
#spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html # Content-Type value.
#spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true # Enable MVC Thymeleaf view resolution.
#spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8 # Template encoding.
spring.thymeleaf.excluded-view-names= # Comma-separated list of view names that should be excluded from resolution.
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5 # Template mode to be applied to templates. See also StandardTemplateModeHandlers.
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/ # Prefix that gets prepended to view names when building a URL.
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html # Suffix that gets appended to view names when building a URL.
#spring.thymeleaf.template-resolver-order= # Order of the template resolver in the chain.
spring.thymeleaf.view-names= # Comma-separated list of view names that can be resolved.
```

[image]

Error:

```
2017-05-22 19:29:24.484  INFO 9500 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-TFU8BCE with PID 9500 (D:\erp\build\classes\main started by admin in D:\erp)
2017-05-22 19:29:24.486  INFO 9500 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-05-22 19:29:24.767  INFO 9500 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5747b69: startup date [Mon May 22 19:29:24 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-22 19:29:27.189  INFO 9500 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-22 19:29:27.740  INFO 9500 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-05-22 19:29:28.490  WARN 9500 --- [  restartedMain] .t.AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ # Prefix that gets prepended to view names when building a URL. (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2017-05-22 19:29:28.613  INFO 9500 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-05-22 19:29:28.648  INFO 9500 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-05-22 19:29:28.657  INFO 9500 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2017-05-22 19:29:28.727  INFO 9500 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 4.597 seconds (JVM running for 5.201)
2017-05-22 19:29:28.730  INFO 9500 --- [       Thread-9] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5747b69: startup date [Mon May 22 19:29:24 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-05-22 19:29:28.732  INFO 9500 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2017-05-22 19:29:28.734  INFO 9500 --- [       Thread-9] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-05-22 19:29:28.735  INFO 9500 --- [       Thread-9] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What is the mean of `Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'` and `Process finished with exit code 0`?

How I do for access http://localhost:8080/greeting success?

Comment: Errm, it created an EntityManagerFactory, and then at the end closed it. That is no error.

Comment: What is "exit code 0"? Does this code generate by JVM, IntelliJ IDEA or Spring Boot? How to access http://localhost:8080/greeting success?

Comment: I think the error is Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ # Prefix that gets prepended to view names when building a URL. (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration). Hence the application is gracefully shutting your EntityManagerFactory

Comment: Exit code 0 ... i.e no error.

Comment: I try comment line `classpath:/templates/`, but not success. and I also has directory `templates` inside `resources` (it is classpath)

Comment: Add @SpringBootApplication annotation above ServletInitializer. Probably the spring boot app doesn't start at all.

Comment: @DVy got any solution? (Sorry for asking after a long time)

Comment: I was facing the same problem, and the reason was the heap size (-Xmx64m) was so small, so once we increase the heap size (-Xmx512m) the error was gone.